# Flex 4 and states! Im sick to always have to set the normal and disabled state in custom components

Tags: flex4, custom-component

I'm extending the SkinnableContainer in the hosted component. so in the mxml file i always have to make the normal and disabled states. the problem is that when i make changes in the design mode, the elements get like this: width.normal="xx" and other thing when i would like to be generic like width="xx".

where are the options to disable this?
it is possible to don't have to make the normal and disabled state in custom components?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found something that might help me and others with the same issue: design view-> right click on design area -> Apply Current Properties to All States

then removes all the [property].[state] and sets as [property]. cleaner now!